# Webbrowser to ChefSharp Update

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, cefsharp

I'm trying to switch from the normal Webbrowser control (IE) at vb.net to CefSharp (ChromiunWebBrowser).

In the WebBrowser Control (IE), for example, I would have implemented a button click like this

```
Public Sub SetWebbrowserTagIDClick(ByVal TagName As String, ByVal TagID As String, ByVal Attribute As String, ByVal AttributeValue As String)
Dim ElementListe As HtmlElementCollection = Nothing
        ElementListe = Mainform.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(TagID).GetElementsByTagName(TagName)
        For Each Element As HtmlElement In ElementListe
            If InStr(Element.GetAttribute(Attribute).ToString, AttributeValue) > 0 Then
              Element.InvokeMember("Click")
              Exit For
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```

Is there a way to implement it in cefSharp in the same way or do I always have to go through Javascript?

In the web browser it didn't matter if I only addressed a class name. In cefSharp, isn't it difficult?

Warm greetings from Germany

Comment: Using JavaScript is likely the fastest option, should translate into a few lines no problem. Not sure what you mean by addressed a class name? You can likely directly obtain the element using a query selector.

Comment: I am working on a CefSharp specific port of puppeteer Sharp which will allow for a different approach to accessing the DOM. Project is usable, just not a lot of documentation yet https://github.com/cefsharp/Puppeteer#cefsharp-puppeteer there are plenty of unit tests https://github.com/cefsharp/Puppeteer/tree/main/lib/PuppeteerSharp.Tests/QuerySelectorTests